# The Fourier transform of a damped cosine and the units of the result

Tags: fourier-transform, power-spectral-density

If I take a simple transient voltage signal of the form
$$f(t) = V_p e^{-t/\tau} \cos(\omega_0 t)$$
and take the Fourier transform in the normal way
$$F(\omega) = \frac{V_p}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int^{+\infty}_{0}  e^{-t/\tau} \cos(\omega_0 t)  e^{-i \omega t} \ \ dt $$
giving the result 
$$F(\omega) = \frac{V_p}{2\sqrt{w\pi}} \left( \frac{1}{1/\tau - i (\omega_{0} - \omega)} + \frac{1}{1/\tau + i (\omega_{0} + \omega)} \right)$$
Seeing as I am interested in a Lorentzian like function, I ignore the second term in the bracket -- and then take the absolute-squared value of what is left giving 
$$\left|F(\omega)\right|^{2} = \frac{V^{2}_{p}}{2 \pi}\frac{1}{(2/\tau)^{2} + 4(\omega - \omega_{0})^{2}}$$ which when making the approximation of $2/\tau = \Delta\omega$ the linewidth gives a quantity in units of $[V^{2}/Hz^{2}]$. Consistent with a power spectrum density.

This is the crux of my question as if I consider what really happens with a measurement say on a signal/spectrum analyser, the time transient voltage is dissipated over the input impedance of the signal/spectrum analyser, which will have a thermal Johnson-Nyqist noise of $[V/\sqrt{Hz}]$ -- and define my noise floor.

I feel that my result should somehow have the same units, that a spectral lineshape, originating from the FT of a time transient voltage signal should have either units of $[V/\sqrt{Hz}]$ or $[V^{2}/Hz]$. How can I rectify my inconsistency with units as in the end I wish to write something like
$$PSD = \sqrt{\left|F(\omega)\right|^{2} + e_{n}^{2}}$$
Where $e_{n}$ (units of $[V/\sqrt{Hz}]$) is the noise floor of my spectrum.

---

Some additional thought. I believe this problem can be rectified by the definition of the Power Spectrum density
$$S(\omega) = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{T} |F(\omega)|^{2}$$
this factor of $1/T$ takes care of the dimensionality problem -- however I am unsure how to apply this equation as it seems to be in the limit just sends the function to zero because of the $1/T$ factor.

Comment: can we change your voltage symbol from "$f(t)$" to "$v(t)$" and reserve "$f$" for frequency, if we come to it?  i am refraining from editing your question for a little while to let you respond.  ...  And does your damped sinusoid have a Heaviside unit step (EEs usually call it "$u(t)$") attached to it?

Comment: No problem, I usually use $\nu$ or $\omega$ for frequency, but let's go with $f$. And I don't include a Heaviside as by changing my lower integration limit from $-\infty$ to $0$ I thought this takes care of it?

Comment: ok you added the answer while I was preparing it :))

Comment: @Fat32 sort of you have the final piece I think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define PSD proportional to $|X(\omega)|^2$, whose unit is $V^2 \cdot s^2$, where $X(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of the input signal $x(t)$ in units of Volts. But this quantity is not a PSD but ESD (Energy Spectral Density) used for energy signals instead.

You shall define PSD for periodic signals with a normalization by time:

$$ \text{PSD_x} = \frac{1}{T} |X(\omega)|^2 $$

Where $T$ is the observation wime with units of seconds. Without this division, longer signals would seem to have more power, which is not what you want to see; they have more energy but the same power.

Units of this PSD will be $V^2 \cdot s = V^2 / Hz$ and its square root $V / \sqrt{Hz}$.

Comment: THANK YOU! You're the first person to give me a straight answer! I have always been using the definition where $T \rightarrow \infty$ which obviously just tends to zero! Is there a proof that says that a finite time Fourier transform PSD can be normalised like this? Maybe related to my other question https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/61825/determine-a-power-spectrum-desnity-from-a-fourier-transform-of-finite-time

Comment: The proof (derivation) is laid out in many standard signal processing and communication theory books. Essentially, the infinite limit will yield zero average power for *energy signals* but nonzero for *power signals*. The finite length division will always yield nonzero average power, however it will stay the same for power signals, while it will decrease to zero as $T$ increases for energy signals.

Comment: The green tick is yours, incidently, could you recommend such a text? My field is not electronic engineering or signal analysis  -- I work in experimental trapped ion physics.

Comment: You can find the definition of *power spectral density* and *energy spectral density* from the following book: Communication Systems_Haykin_4E, page 44-50. However they use Random Process terminology and not practical measurements. More generally you may read the following texts: Signals and Systems_Oppenheim, Communication System Engineering_Proakis. They are heavily signal processing oriented however.

Comment: Much obliged to you!

Comment: You're welcome..!

Answer (score 3):

if $v(t)$ is an electromotive force (a voltage expressed in units of **volt**) that is a function of time (let's say expressed in units of **second**), then the Fourier Transform (or the Laplace Transform):

$$ \mathscr{F} \Big \{ v(t) \Big \} \triangleq V(i \omega) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} v(t) e^{-i \omega t} \, \mathrm{d}t  $$

will have units of **volt-second**.  And $\omega$ will be in **radian/second**.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, or equivalently, $V/Hz$. I completely agree. But then there is an inconsistency in a number of places in my understanding. One in how I calculate my Fourier transform to be gin with -- because taking the absolute value squared of the Fourier transform should also square all units right? And then seeing as the signal is dissipated over a resistor (e.g. input impedance of a spectrum analyser) which has a thermal noise in units of $V/\sqrt{Hz}$, which I take to be the noise floor of my signal in frequency space. How do I reconcile the unit inconsistencies?

Comment: i think i understand your concern.  lemme ruminate and get back to this.